# In spark,what's the relationship between the num of stages and Parallelism?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

In spark,what's the relationship between the num of stages and Parallelism? **Had better give a example**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your stage consists of the action "count()" on a RDD, the action is split into several tasks that can be done in parallel. The number of tasks is the parallelism.

Comment: I still do not understand, for example, in this pic(http://dl2.iteye.com/upload/attachment/0101/2908/5e281cc2-4a2b-381a-bd78-13e523772a20.jpg), the "groupByKey" stage, how many tasks the stage will spilt and how many tasks will run at the same time? And how to judge these two?

Comment: With groupByKey you can pass the numPartitions parameter, which uses the HashPartitioner to create the the partitions. If you then do an action on the grouped RDD (like count), "numPartitions" tasks will be used for the groupByKey and so for the count.